# Django AJAX Navigation

Tags: ajax, django, view, navigation, django-templates

As a test i have have decided to see if i can get the hashchange navigation trick think working with my django app...

So far i have it at the stage where the hash change triggers and only needs to load the data in, this is where i have problems.

Now, I am new to django and django/ajax and i dont know where to start, did a few googles and had no luck. In a nutshell I need a way to load in the pages without the template using the extend syntax.. Would i just be able to parse an additional value to the url and exclude it from the template?? im not sure

Please give some code guidance or something

Answer (score 0):

Your template creates the html that is sent to the browser, once it reaches the client your template can't make changes on that page, the page would need to be reloaded for the template to make any changes. So your options when the hash change is triggered is to either have the information you want load as part of the page but be hidden, which means you must know everything the user needs when the page loads, or use AJAX. With AJAX we can make changes without reloading the page when the user gives us new information by making a XMLHttpRequest using Javascript, which doesn't have to return XML it can be JSON or even just a singe text string. So when your hash change triggers you will be sending a request to the site, usually a GET or POST, and a script on the site will process the information sent from the client side and respond accordingly. Here is an example that would be inside the change trigger function

```
data = "somedata";
request = new XMLHttpRequest(); //create the request object
request.open("POST", "app/handler", false); // set its parameters
request.send("data="+data); // send it to the server
response = request.responseText; // get the response
responseHandler(response) // do something with the data the server sent back
```

On the server side this could be the sole purpose of the app. All the formatting can be done with the base template, javascript and css for the site. Just load the new information after each response. There are some AJAX libraries for Django, check out [the wiki page](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/AJAX) or look into the django.core.serialization which will let you return your apps model as json, xml or yaml.

```
from django.core import serializers 
def my_json_view(request):
    data = serializers.serialize("json", MyModel.objects.all()[:5])
    return HttpResponse(data, mimetype="application/javascript")
```